# Find Members Belonging to Multiple Groups in Specified OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have an OU called PEOPLE GROUPS.

Users should not belong to more than one PEOPLE GROUP.

Need to find all users who belong to more than one group in the PEOPLE GROUPS OU.

Comment: Could you update the question with what you have tried and a what isn't working? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with something like this:

```
Get-AdGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $PeopleGroupOU -SearchScope Subtree | ForEach-Object {
    $PeopleGroupDN = $_.DistinguishedName;
    $_ | Get-AdGroupMember | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserDN = $_.DistinguishedName;
            PeopleGroupDN = $PeopleGroupDN;
        }
    }
} | Group-Object -Property UserDN | Where-Object {
    $_.Count -gt 1;
}
```

You might need `Get-AdGroupMember -Recurse` if you use nested groups in your People Groups.

I'm sure this could be written faster, but this is the most straightforward PowerShell way to do it.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!  You saved me hours of work.  Thanks much!